# Title image in LaTeX double column

Tags: floats

How do I add a title image in the first page in a double-column `LaTeX` template?

I tried the following, but the image crosses to the right column

```
\titlepic{\includegraphics[image.png}}
```

Basically, I need an environment like `figure*` but for a title image. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! It's hard for us to tell what's happening with only one line of code and few details. Could you please edit your question to include the complete code needed to show your problem? That is, it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, but delete all packages unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

The only code that you show is erroneous, but this causes a fatal error (= no output), not what you said (="the image crosses to the right column").

As pointed the comments, it is not possible guess the true problem without an example document, but the fact that you are using a template smells bad, because  `\titlepic` used correctly should work just as you expected in the standard article class with the `twocolumn` option:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{You}
\date{Some time ago}
\titlepic{\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you template is not using a standard class, most probably is relevant this warning from the manual:

> **Note**: titlepic only works with the default document classes article, report and book.

Alternatively, with other classes as `memoir` you can try to do the same but without `titlepic`:

```
\documentclass{article} % also work with memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{You}
\date{Some time ago}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\maketitle
{\centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}\bigskip\par}]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```